# Error while loading nodelet [/velocity_multiplexer]

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, amcl-pose, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using **ROS fuerte version** on Ubuntu 10.04. I use the **velocity multiplexer (sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-yujin-ocs)** designed by YujinRobot(http://wiki.ros.org/cmd_vel_mux). I modify the one header file and one cpp file in the installed package, to incorporate one more subsrciber (so that nodelet manager subcribes to amcl_pose topic).

I compile the code and it gets compiled perfectly.

**root@ubuntu:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/yujin_ocs/cmd_vel_mux# make**

But when I RUN following command:

**roslaunch cmd_vel_mux standalone.launch**

The ***errors*** can be found below::

http://pastebin.com/XnUkXRCZ

Some files that you may be interested are given below:::::

**CMakeList.txt**
http://pastebin.com/FfJaZF7v

**nodelet_plugins.xml**
http://pastebin.com/S1ZxgW9M

**header file**
http://pastebin.com/PcuNaWYm

**Source cpp file**
http://pastebin.com/gZUfqEu3

**manifest.xml**
http://pastebin.com/vS0w7Tiq

Question1:: why the error  says "Make sure that you are calling the **PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML.**"???

Question2:: why **new function APPEARS to be UNDEFINED??** Even if it is included in Header File and there is **no problem in compiling the new package.**

**Please HELP**

**NOTE**
In CMakeLists.txt (http://pastebin.com/zCzZ7fG6), even if we **link directories explicitly, still '.so' file can't  figure it out where the cpp or header file**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/157886/error-while-loading-nodelet-%5B/velocity_multiplexer%5D/) by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2014-04-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-04-27**:
Is the function that it can't find implemented with exactly the same name?

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-04-27**:
I have uploaded the 'source cpp file with highlighted portion.' There is no such mistakes, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're implementing your new function in the global namespace, rather than within the class.

In you cpp file, you have a global function:

```
void currentPosCallback(const geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped::ConstPtr& msg)
```

But it should be namespaced to your class:

```
void CmdVelMux::currentPosCallback(const geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped::ConstPtr& msg)
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-04-28**:
Yes, you are correct @ahendrix thank you once again............